# Populating a lookup list from another list and then updating that list with the new value?

Tags: workflow

Apologies if my question is hard to understand - I'm unsure of the proper terminology to use.

What I want to do is the following...

As an example, I have a list called "Sales" that contains a column called "Customer". "Customer" is populated as a lookup from a list called "customerList". The user selects the customer from the drop-down when completing the Sales form.

However, sometimes the customer will not be in the list and needs to be added, so there is another field in the form called "New Customer". When the form is submitted a workflow adds the new customer to customerList so that it is then available for future users to select.

How can I do this AND update the Sales list record that has just been submitted so that the new customer is added to the Customer field as well as the New Customer field?

I hope that makes sense!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If what I'm understanding is correct, you should be able to, in Step 1, create item in customerList.  Then in Step 2, update 'Current Item' with the value from customerList that correlates to newly created item.

In order to populate a a lookup column, you will need to return the ID value of the newly created customer in the Customer List.  See [this example](https://sharepointdiva.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/create-new-list-item-with-lookup-fields-in-workflow/)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that would do it, but I don't want the users to have to go and update customerList manually if their customer isn't already there. It needs to be streamlined so they only complete a single form.